# How to assign values in bash after running commands

Tags: bash

```
NAME=aaa/bbbbb:0.1.2
```

How can I assign the new string?

```
NEW_VAR=$NAME | sed 's/.*\///' | cut -f1 -d":"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using bash, you don't actually need to shell out to other commands, there is built in string mangling functions:

```
NEW_VAR=${NAME%%:*}
```

If you would prefer to, it'll be something like this:

```
NEW_VAR=$(echo -n $NAME | cut -f1 -d":")
```